# Knockoutjs if/shim binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to create a custom binding that behaves like the `if` binding, but instead of removing the element entirely, it replaces it with another element of the same height whenever it should be removed.

I'm struggling to find a way of doing this that isn't hacky. I don't know enough about the internals of knockout to go about this in an educated way.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you solve it by combining `if: [condition]` with `css: { shim: [condition] }` and then hide your content in css: `.shim { visibility: hidden }`?

Comment: Good idea. I need more than a pure css solution as I need to set the height of `.shim` to the height of the removed elements at the point of removal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.shim = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {

        // First get the latest data that we're bound to
        var value = valueAccessor();

        // Next, whether or not the supplied model property is observable, get its current value
        var shim = ko.unwrap(value);

        if (shim) {
            var shimEl = $(element).data('shim');
            // Create the shim element if not created yet
            if (!shimEl) {
                shimEl = $('<div />').addClass('shim').appendTo(element);
                // Equal the height of the elements
                shimEl.height($(element).height());
                $(element).data('shim', shimEl);
            }
            shimEl.show();
        } else {
            var shimEl = $(element).data('shim');
            if (shimEl) {
                shimEl.hide();
            }
        }

        // You can also trigger the if-binding at this point
        // ko.bindingHandlers.if.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings);
    }
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
<div data-bind="shim: [condition]"></div>
```

Comment: Ah this is great - the delegation down to the `if` binding was the missing piece. Thanks!

Comment: Couple of notes on getting this working. The `if` binding requires an `init` too. Also, you need to pass the opposite value of `valueAccessor` as a function in your calls to `ko.bindingHandlers.if.update`. Otherwise, solution works perfectly and I really appreciate your help!